# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-error-1064

This is the complete error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Id,ActivityDay,Calories
1503960366,4/12/2016,1985
1503960366,4/13/2016,1797
1503' at line 1
```

i am just trying to import a csv file from my download folder of pc to my database using import database function in mysql workbench. Import is completed BUT  with this one error .

Comment: Looks like you try import not CSV but .SQL dump.